# Javascript parsing using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Is there any module to parse javascript using node.js . I mean we are able to add and remove html content dynamically using cheerio nodejs module.

Similarly, we want to add, remove and manipulate a javascript method/variable. Is there any module to do that. I searched but unable to get one.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Do you just want `eval()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the `recast` module. Install it via `npm install --save recast`. Below is a sample program that will read in the source of a module named `user.js` in the current directory. It will parse the source into an AST then from the AST re-generate the original source. Modify the AST with help from `estraverse` before you call `recast.print(ast).code`.

The source (does not incorporate `estraverse` -- exercise for the reader):

```
'use strict';

var recast = require('recast');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = path.resolve(__dirname, 'user.js');
var code = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
var ast = recast.parse(code);

var output = recast.print(ast).code;

console.log(output);
```